# java sorting a integers linked list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, linked-list, swap

i created a linked list of integers but i didn't know how to sort it ! 
iv tried a lot but always the number's that was inside the list gone away 
this is the code that i used for my linked list !

```
import java.util.Random;

class Node {
Node next;
int num;

public Node(int val) {
    num = val;
    next = null;
}
}

public class LinkedList {

Node head;

public LinkedList(int val) {
    head = new Node(val);
}

public void append(int val) {
    Node tmpNode = head;
    while (tmpNode.next != null) {
        tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
    }
    tmpNode.next = new Node(val);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rn=new Random();
    int min=0;
    int max=1000;
    LinkedList myList = new LinkedList(rn.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min);
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        int x=rn.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        myList.append(x);
    }
    myList.print();
}
}
```

Comment: There are a number of ways to sort an array: merge sort, quick sort, bubble sort, and more. You should know how to implement a number of those. Google is your friend here. :)

Comment: Sorting a linked list is a little tricky, as it doesn't have random access. In you want to use a standard sorting algorithm you are probably better copying the data to an array and sorting that.

Comment: If you want ONLY ordering on Integers, I suggest you to use TreeSet instead of LinkedList.

Comment: @MohamedBathaoui those two are **completely different**. Most obviously, a `TreeSet` doesn't support duplicates. Because it's a `Set`.

Comment: Yes, I agree @BoristheSpider . That's why I mentionned the "ONLY" word. All is about sorting Integers for his case.

Comment: @MohamedBathaoui the OP doesn't say **unique** integers - therefore a `Set` is not appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

This line

```
LinkedList myList = new LinkedList(rn.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min);
```

Doesn't seem to make a lot of sense according to [the LinkedList API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). And you should really use Java's LinkedLists, instead of rolling your own, so you can make use of the List and Collection APIs and Generics.

Once you're using java.util.LinkedList You might like to call

```
myList.sort();
```

to sort the list, or provide a Comparator with it, like so:

```
  import java.util.Comparator;
  import java.util.LinkedList;

  Comparator<Integer> order = Integer::compare;
  myList.sort(order.reversed());
```

By the way Boris the Spider's comment is spot on. This is how java 8's standard implementation does it for LinkedLists, it makes the list an array, sorts the array in O(n log n) and then just puts every item at it's place in O(n):

```
 default void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) { //O(n log n)
    Object[] a = this.toArray(); //O(n)
    Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator) c); //O(n log n)
    ListIterator<E> i = this.listIterator();
    for (Object e : a) { //O(n)
        i.next();      //O(1)
        i.set((E) e);  //O(1)
    }
}
```

By the way: I don't see any implementation of the "print()" method in your code. Sure that it prints the correct value?
And I don't see any implementation of a sort method in your code, so how could we know how the numbers get lost while sorting?

Comment: if i want to use the linked list from java ... I'v all ready did but i don't want to use it ... i'v been asked to do this

Comment: As you know, indexed access to a linked list is O(n) - or O(n/2), if you save a reference to the first and last element and cose the shorter path.
Setting every value on every list node is therefore an O(n) operation n times, which amounts to O(n²).
You can build a list faster than that - you might create a _new_ list from the sorted array, which is an O(n) Operation added to the O(n log n) sort operation, which amounts to O(n log n). The above original source Code from the JDK8 List interface does not do that, in JDK8 LinkedList does use the default method, go figure.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Dang, sorry, you're right, I just mistook indexed access with iterated Access. I will correct the answer.

Comment: Much better! The only problem is that this answer is about Java's `LinkedList` whereas the question is about the OP's custom `LinkedList`. So the first part of the answer is not relevant - the OP's ctor sets the `head` node.

Comment: No matter if you roll your own LinkedList (not advised), the sorting strategy can work the same way, unless the requirements state you need to sort in-line. Apart from that, the original poster has chosen to not post both his print() method and his sort-attempt, which means we effectively cannot answer his question why his list content get lost on sorting. 
Effectively he asked a question that can't be answered.